# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication + Heroku

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, heroku

При деплойе приложения на Хероку получаю `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication`.
Ниже мой `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ua.sillmarry</groupId>
<artifactId>ArtToolsBot</artifactId>
<version>v.09.06.21.0.3.6</version>
<name>ArtToolsBot</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<description>Project for ArtTools Telegram Bot</description>

<properties>

    <java.version>16</java.version>
    <telegrambots.version>5.2.0</telegrambots.version>
    <spring.version>2.4.5</spring.version>
    <start-class>ua.sillmarry.ArtToolsBot.ArtToolsBotApplication</start-class>

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring Group -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SQL Group -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.23</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.30.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Telegram Bot API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
        <version>${telegrambots.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>

</project>
```

и Main:

```
package ua.sillmarry.ArtToolsBot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ArtToolsBotApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ArtToolsBotApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавил в `pom.xml`:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
</parent>
```